# Design pattern: inheritance and encapsulated inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, encapsulation

I got problems formulating it precisely so I left more general description in the title (if you have more precise description of the problem, please comment, I'll edit the title).

The problem: Two classes `AudioStream` and `VideoStream` are derived from base class `MediaStream` which has some common for audio and video stream methods, but is not intended to be used as-is. Consequently, there are two classes `AudioStreamSettings` and `VideoStreamSettings` which are derived from `MediaStreamSettings` and passed to the constructors of their corresponding stream classes. `MediaStreamSettings` stores settings common for audio and video, and base class `MediaStream` accesses this data. The question is: what would be the best way to design this hierarchical relationship between base classes of streams and settings?

I can think of a quick solution like the following:

```
class MediaStream {
public:
  MediaStream(const MediaStreamSettings& settings){
    // do nothing, let derived classes initialize settings_
    // note: I feel guilty for doing this...
  }
  virtual ~MediaStream(){}
protected:
  std::shared_ptr<MediaStreamSettings> settings_;
};

class VideoStream : public MediaStream {
public:
  VideoStream(const VideoStreamSettings& settings):
    MediaStream(settings)
  {
    settings_ = std::make_shared<VideoStreamSettings>(settings);
  }

  void doSomething(){
    int s1 = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<VideoStream, MediaStream>(settings_)->getVideoStreamSetting1();
    ...
  }
};

class AudioStream : public MediaStream {
public:
  AudioStream(const AudioStreamSettings& settings):
    MediaStream(settings)
  {
    settings_ = std::make_shared<AudioStreamSettings>(settings);
  }
}
```

To summarize I'm not comfortable with two things in this approach:

1. not initializing `settings_` in base class (should I make it abstract to calm myself?)
2. using `dynamic_pointer_cast` every time I need to access settings in derived classes (should I make a method wrapper for this?)

Comment: Since the base class provides the `settings_` data member, it should initialize that member. Its constructor should then take an argument that either provides the full settings object directly, or that serves as a factory to produce it. However, the problematic thing here is the potential sharing of settings between multiple objects created by copying. Better make that `MediaStream` non-copyable. And then a `unique_ptr` would be better suited.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thanks! at first, I actually tried to use `unique_ptr` but then got stuck with `dynamic_pointer_cast` for that. I agree, `shared_ptr` won't be appropriate here. I guess a combination of having `unique_ptr` and abstract method described by @Jarod42 answer would be a better design

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to not store data in `MediaStream` and add a virtual method

```
virtual const MediaStreamSettings& GetMediaStreamSettings() const = 0;
```

Comment: thanks! I like this approach. plus, I'll try to use `unique_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr` for `settings_`. I'll keep question open for a while to let people give more alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Since MediaStream should not be used as-is, making it an abstract class should be acceptable (and desirable).
Thus providing implementation (which includes class members) is pointless.

```
class IMediaStream {
public:
    virtual ~IMediaStream() {}
    virtual void play() = 0;
    virtual std::shared_ptr<MediaSettings> getSettings() = 0;
private:
    IMediaStream() {}
};

template<Setting>
class MediaStream : public IMediaStream {
public:
    MediaStream(const Setting& settings){
        settings_ = std::make_shared<Setting>(settings);
    }
    virtual ~MediaStream() {}
    virtual void play() override {
        // Implementation here
    }
    virtual std::shared_ptr<MediaSettings> getSettings() override {
        return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Setting, MediaSettings>();
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Setting> settings_;
}

// Alternatively you can inherit or specialize
// the template to add your implementation
typedef MediaStream<VideoStreamSettings> VideoStream;
typedef MediaStream<AudioStreamSettings> AudioStream;
```

Comment: thanks! I guess I'll need to inherit as `VideoStream` and `AudioStream` have to do some operations specific to their type. but using templates here is a nice idea! I'll consider that